# How to extract rows with conditions on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to return all columns for a unique value of `Col1` and `Col2` if `Col3` is not `9`. For example for a given dataframe `df` the returned dataframe will be `selected`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
'Col1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
'Col2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,'A','A','A','B','B','AA',1,1,2,2,2,3,3,'A','A','A','B','B','AA','AA','BA'], 
'Col3': [1,2,3,9,1,5,9,6,9,2,6,7,8,9,5,3,9,7,8,9,3,7,3,7,9,7,9,5,9,5]
})
```

```py
selected= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
'Col1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
'Col2': ['A','A','A','AA',3,3,'BA'], 
'Col3': [2,6,7,5,3,7,5]
})
```

here is my code I tried.

```py
selected = {'Col1': [], 'Col2' : [], 'Col3':[]}
for i in df.Col1.unique():
    for val in df[df['Col1'] == i].Col2.unique():
        val2 = df[df['Col2'] == val].Col3.values
        if val2.any() == 9:
            pass
        else:
            selected['Col1'].append(i)
            selected['Col2'].append(val)
            selected['Col3'].append(val2)

selected =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(selected)
```

Here is the error I get:

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: Can you posted text for your dataframe instead of a picture?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: I just posted text for dataframe including the code

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your sample data and tried to understand the question that you are trying to ask.

**Dataset** - Looking at the expected data from the whole dataset, Column 3 doesn't consists of any repeated values or duplicates.

You can filter your whole dataset using drop_duplicates().

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["col3"])
```

Also, I would appreciate if you post a question; rather than commenting it, Like the manner you posted about your dataset.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!